# Moving id attribute to parent tag using GREP

Tags: html, grep

I have a webpage that was built several years ago by someone who didn't know how to apply id attributes to an HTML tag, so they created a named anchor instead. I'd like to clean up the code by moving the ids to the parent tag. Doing it by hand is slow and tedious, so I was hoping to use GREP to speed things up. But this is beyond my skills with GREP.

The code can appear in one of three ways:

```
1)    <p><a id="baking" name="baking"></a><strong>Baking.</strong> Cooking with dry heat in an enclosed vessel such as an oven or in a large lidded pot.</p>


2)   <p><a name="baking" id="baking"></a><strong>Baking.</strong> Cooking with dry heat in an enclosed vessel such as an oven or in a large lidded pot.</p>
```

or,

```
3)   <p><a id="baking"></a><strong>Baking.</strong> Cooking with dry heat in an enclosed vessel such as an oven or in a large lidded pot.
```

The desired code should look like this:

```
<p id="baking"><strong>Baking.</strong> Cooking with dry heat in an enclosed vessel such as an oven or in a large lidded pot.</p>
```

1. Move the id to the parent tag.
2. Remove the original named anchor `<a>`...

There are over a hundred entries in this list. I could run three separate GREP routines to pick out all the variants, but I'm assuming that this can be done with one statement.

Thanks

Comment: `grep` only finds text.  It does not modify text.  For that, you need `sed`.

Comment: I am using Dreamweaver to search and replace. If I could get a search statement, Dreamweaver can do the rest.

Typically, I enter something like `<table table[^>]*>(.+)</table>` in the find window and then `<div>$1</div>` to swap table tags for div tags.

Comment: What I need is a search statement that will pick up the id attribute regardless of how it appears in the code and then stick it into the p tag.

For example, I could find "`<p><a (id="baking")></a>`"

...and then replace it with `<p $1>`

Answer (score 2):

OK, I was able to do what I wanted by just performing three separate FIND/CHANGE operations. I was hoping to do it using a single one.

Here are the three expressions that I used:

1) `<p><a id="(.+)" name="[^>]*"></a>`

...allowed me to find the ids that lead the structure.

2) `<p><a name="[^>]*" id="(.+)"></a>`

...allowed me to find the ids that appear at the end of the structure.

3) `<p><a id="(.+)"></a>`

...allowed me to find the ids that appear alone.

Then, I inserted the content of the found id attribute and recreated the id in the parent tag using Dreamweaver's CHANGE field, such as `<p id="$1">`

I'm sure you can cobble these three expressions into one statement, but I couldn't figure it out.

In the end, this worked. Much faster than doing it by hand.